# Async TCP write to stream does not work with await

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

I am trying to get some async TCP stuff going on. Here I am just sending data to a client from the server using a method Send(). It sends fine but I don't seem to be making any use out of the await modifier. In fact when I use it my second message does not actually send through the TCP socket, although it does call its method.

**Send a message to the client**

```
private async Task Send(TcpClient client, CancellationToken ct, string message) {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending Message " + message);
            message += "<EOF>";
            using (client) {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

If I do this, both messages make it to the client

```
            Send(tcpClient, ct, "Message1");
            Send(tcpClient, ct, "Message2");
```

If I use await, both Sends fire (at least Console.WriteLine is called) but only Message1 is showing up on my client.

```
            await Send(tcpClient, ct, "Message1");
            await Send(tcpClient, ct, "Message2");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am a bit surprised that this will work more than once anyway (you got very lucky in the first instance) because you `Dispose` your used `TcpClient` right after the first call went through with `using (client) {  ... }` you surely don't want to do that here ...

Comment: You are disposing the TcpClient inside the first send. Try removing it.

Comment: Then my client is the issue, as this is server code. If I remove `using (client)` form the supplied code, my client application hangs on `if(stream.DataAvailable) return reader.ReadLine();` I call this every update and append to a string. Then if an EOF is found it is dealt with. Obviously I am still missing something on the client..